# Constructing an Isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-space-isomorphism

I need to construct an isomorphism:

> $T: W \to C^3$

where W is a subspace of $P_3(C)$

I got bases (for W and $C^3$ respectively)

> $\alpha = \{(ix + 1),\ \ (x^3 + 2x),  \ (2ix^2 + ix -1)\}$
>
> $\beta = \{ (1,0,0),\ (0,1,0),\ (0,0,1)\}$

obviously

> $[T]_{\beta\alpha} = \matrix{1\ \ \ 0\ \ \  0\\0\ \ \ 1\ \ \  0\\0\ \ \ 0\ \ \  1\\}$

but how do I find an explicit formula T(p(x))?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $T$ sends $a(ix+1)+b(x^3+2x)+c(2ix^2+ix-1)$ onto $(a,b,c)$. If you want something more explicit, you can write

$$a(ix+1)+b(x^3+2x)+c(2ix^2+ix-1)=bx^3+2ic \cdot x^2+(2b+ic)\cdot x+(a-c)$$

So your map sends a polynomial $\alpha x^3+\beta x^2+\gamma x+\delta$ onto $(\delta+\beta/(2i),\alpha,\beta/(2i))$.

(Of course not all polynomials belong to your subspace).

Comment: Oh, now I see the way. Thank you

Comment: did you mean $\gamma$x?
on the 4th line

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.